# how do i detect if a peice of text was included in a input() line? **PYTHON**

Tags: windows-7, python-3.8

**python**

i am so stuck please help me,

say if i did

```
dad = input(is your dad round or a square? )
```

and put put in "my dad is round"
what i want it to do detect if it includes
i tried

```
if dad includes "round"
```

but that does not exist

note, i do know if i do

```
if dad == "in my dad is round":
```

but i want to see if it includes it not it it is it if that makes sense.

Comment: How many different versions of Python are you using?

Comment: `dad = input(is your dad round or a square? )` isn't valid Python.

Answer (score 0):

Right idea, wrong syntax:

```
if "round" in dad:
```

Answer (score 0):

You just use:

```
dad = input("is your dad round or a square?")
if "round" in dad:
# Do Something
```